# How to set up Django and React project without having to deal with CORS?

Tags: django, reactjs

So I've been working on a React project that sends requests to the Django REST-API. The problem is, I can't seem to get around the problem of the CORS. The front end is totally isolated to the backend. In order to make sure the website works properly, I need to have Django serve the front end files. I'm not sure where to start, How do I set up Django + React environment so I don't have to deal with the CORS issue?

Comment: You can't "not have to deal with CORS issues". It's a browser security. You have to deal with it. What is your actual issue? Is your API on another domain than HTML pages you serve?

Comment: Also, have you read this? http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/#cors

Comment: From the documentation Antoine Pinsard linked: _"The best way to deal with CORS in REST framework is to add the required response headers in middleware. This ensures that CORS is supported transparently, without having to change any behavior in your views."_

Comment: @AntoinePinsard, But if I get Django to serve the front-end files, I wouldn't have to deal with it right? Wouldn't that be the same origin ?

Comment: @Pranay Yes - you also do not need to make django doing it - you might also use your webserver configuration to serve the static react pages next to your django, but on different paths in one server block (nginx).

Comment: @dahrens That seems like a good idea, any pointers on how I can do it?
Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: read this [blog post](http://oskarhane.com/avoid-cors-with-nginx-proxy_pass/)

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with it (also with backend written in DJANGO) is that my react app uses NodeJs for server-side-rendering and forwarding api requests. This allows me to forward request on Node server to django server.

take a look a this nodejs - express server implementation:

```
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'
import compression from 'compression'
import React from 'react'
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import configureStore from 'data/redux/store';
import proxy from 'http-proxy-middleware';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl';
import routes from './routes';

const store = configureStore();
const app = express();
app.use(compression());

//template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//where to look for templates
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public'));
//Serve static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public'), { index: false }));

//middleware for handling api request
app.use('/api/*', proxy({
    target: process.env.API_HOST,
    pathRewrite: { '^/api/': '' },
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
}));

app.use('/media/*', proxy({
    target: process.env.API_HOST,
    changeOrigin: true,
    secure: false,
}));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    match({ routes: routes(store), location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err.message)
        } else if (redirect) {
            res.redirect(redirect.pathname + redirect.search)
        } else if (props) {
            const appHtml = renderToString(
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <IntlProvider locale="en">
                        <RouterContext store={store} {...props} />
                    </IntlProvider>
                </Provider>
            );
            res.render('index', { appHtml });
        } else {
            res.status(404).send('Not Found')
        }
    })
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('Production Express server running at localhost:' + PORT)
});
```

So I have NodeJS server which servers react apps and handles incoming requests starting with `/api/` by forwarding them to django server and returning back response to client.

Comment: do you have a complete example source code depicting the above flow?

Comment: I don't unfortunately. But example above is all there is to it. Even webpack-dev-server provides this functionality. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I could do this by loosely coupling django with react. Works like this: I started a new npm project with webpack in a folder inside the app I needed the react frontend (my_app/react_frontend). So I built my react frontend on this folder, which has a index.html (the public one) inside. This index.html becomes a template file for one index view I create in views.py on the main url (render(index.html)). Next you need a middleware for django to deal with webpack. I use this small library here: https://github.com/ezhome/django-webpack-loader. You will have to configure the folders carefully in settings.py and webpack.config.js, following this library's docs, for example including the react_frontend folder in your templates settings.

Finally I run my webpack dev-server on watch mode together with django dev server to develop. This is, my start script in packages.json is `"start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch"`

This way, my react frontend is coupled to django only on index.html. All ajax calls to backend are directed to DRF views directly. I did't have to deal with CORS problems this way. The CSFR problem is straightfoward, as I just had to put {% csrf_token %} on the index.html file.
I hope this helps.